# How can I downsample a texture using FBOs?

Tags: opengl, textures

I am rendering a scene to FBO as my render target whose size is 8 times the size of the orignal screen in OpenGL. Now i wan to downsample the texture generated by FBO to the size of the screen so as to achieve spatial anti aliasing. How do i achieve the down sampling ? Please provide implementation details.
**Note : If there is a better way of doing anti aliasing in FBOs please mention that too. I am trying to remove the aliasing in the image attached below.**

[image]

Comment: I feel sorry for your GPU

Comment: How are you drawing the grid?

Comment: @NicolBolas a texture for 1X1 sqaure block and then I am mapping it all over the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Since your render target is exactly 8 times the size of the screen, I'd just use `glGenerateMipmap`, after setting `glTexParameteri(..., GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 3);`. Then, just blit or whatever from mipmap level 3, and you're done.

But really, you're wasting a *lot* of performance by not using multisampling+aniso. Supersampling won't give you much that you won't get with multisampling and anisotropic filtering, and your rendering will be that much faster for it.

Comment: You could also replace blitting with simply drawing a textured sprite that covers the screen area exactly, that also works for non power of 2 scaling.